# Выполнение действий ПОСЛЕ Timer.Once

Tags: c#

```
var send = string.Empty;
((Action)(() => Timer.Once(4, () => {
send = web.GetWithSsl(url);
})))();
var sendDeserialize = JsonHelper.Deserialize<RootObject>(send);\
```

Что я сделал не так?Суть: выполнять var sendDeserialize и остальные действия после выполнения Timer.Once - отправка Get запроса на сайт.

Если я пользуюсь такой схемой

```
var send = string.Empty;
Timer.Once(4, () => {
send = web.GetWithSsl(url);
});
var sendDeserialize = JsonHelper.Deserialize<RootObject>(send);
```

выполняется ДО web.GetWithSsl.

Comment: К сведению: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/554290/178779. Там про javascript, но принцип тот же самый.

Comment: @PavelMayorov я не изучал java так что для меня не понятен тот код :(

Comment: Так напишите ваш код сразу после `GetWithSsl` или в чем проблема?

Comment: @tym32167 проблема в том, что в конце мне нужно вернуть нужный мне флаг - а там получается void и я не могу вернуть тем самым флаг

Comment: Вы понимаете, что делает `Timer.Once`?

Comment: Если вам надо вернуть результат работы, наверное не стоит эту работу через таймер запускать?

Comment: @tym32167 мне нужно через Timer.Once указать отправку смс через 4 секунды и после уже обрабатывать ошибки если есть

Comment: @tym32167 и после обработок ошибок вернуть флаг

Comment: Значит, вам надо дождаться, когда таймер отработает, или выполнить задержку другим способом